# How do I override the CordovaWebViewClient methods in Cordova 6.5.0?

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to override the shouldInterceptRequest() method found here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

So that I can intercept requests that are issued by my app within the Cordova WebView.

I am trying to replicate the method seen here: [Android Phonegap - TIMEOUT ERROR when trying to set a WebViewClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317813/android-phonegap-timeout-error-when-trying-to-set-a-webviewclient)

but it seems as though some of the methods and classes are not recognized (Cordova 6.5.0):

- `this.appView.setWebViewClient()` is not recognized by android studio
- `CordovaWebViewClient` is also giving me syntax error.

Is this method no longer available in newer versions of cordova?

I see there there is something called CordovaWebViewEngine, but I can't find much information on it.

Comment: Closed it as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432072/why-cordovawebviewclient-not-working-in-cordova-6-anymore, see my answer there

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks that was exactly what I needed! Now I've run into another issue, but it is less cordova related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946268/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-an-android-webview